# removing all duplicates of max numbers in a correlation table

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I need code for taking a .csv of a correlation table, sample of the table is posted here:

```
     AA bb  cc  dd  ff
AA  100 87  71  71  78
bb  87  100 73  74  81
cc  71  73  100 96  69
dd  71  74  96  100 71
ee  78  81  69  100 100
ff  72  73  68  68  71
Pg  68  69  62  62  64
Ph  68  69  69  62  64
Pi  68  69  62  62  64
Pj  68  69  63  63  64
Pk  70  71  65  65  67
```

I currently have read the .csv file with python's .csv module as a list of lists. I then removed the first column and row. And am now trying to take these int values and find the max values of each row. If there are multiple max values in a row, I want those values as well.

Then I intend to place that output into a table

```
file1values col row %
group1      AA   AA 100
...
group1      dd   ee 100
group1      ff   ee 100
```

The issue I have so far is getting the max values for each row. Also I think I would be a bit confused on how to get the address (the col and row) for each max value.

Here is code so far:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
import numpy as np


with open('/home/group1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data_as_list = list(reader)

    a = np.array(data_as_list)

    a = np.delete(a, (0), axis=0)

    a = np.delete(a, (0), axis=1)

    np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
    print (a)
    print ('')

    count = 0
    b = (a.astype(int))

    maxArr = []
    while (count < b.shape[0]):
        print (b[count])
        count = count + 1
        maxArr.append(max(b[count - 1]))
    print (maxArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are easier ways...

create a random matrix for tests

```
> import numpy as np
> m=np.random.randint(100,size=(10,10))
```

set diagonal to zero (or set to an out of range negative number)

```
> np.fill_diagonal(m,0)

array([[ 0, 35, 52, 40, 54,  1, 20, 41, 62, 92],
       [45,  0, 75, 71, 85, 86, 83, 39, 52, 69],
       [29, 21,  0, 78, 32, 14, 13, 27, 31, 26],
       [99, 90, 16,  0, 28, 36, 30, 45, 85, 41],
       [29, 21, 48, 31,  0, 86, 18,  7, 70, 76],
       [96, 97, 34, 82, 51,  0, 69, 22, 27, 85],
       [71, 58, 98, 42,  3, 51,  0, 19, 41, 93],
       [54, 97, 86, 75, 62, 91, 78,  0, 55, 89],
       [87, 44, 44, 54, 94, 94, 57, 24,  0, 81],
       [94, 32,  1, 92, 34, 46, 96, 38, 75,  0]])
```

find the maximum values per column/row (since your matrix is symmetric doesn't matter)

```
> cm=np.argmax(m,1)

array([9, 5, 3, 0, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 6])
```

You will need to map the row/column indices to your labels.

```
> for r in range(10): 
      print(r,cm[r],m[r,cm[r]])

0 9 92
1 5 86
2 3 78
3 0 99
4 5 86
5 1 97
6 2 98
7 1 97
8 4 94
9 6 96
```